# case insensitive search in R for loop

Tags: r, rscript

i have the following code:

```
if(projectname %in% checkProjects) {
  print(projectname, "exists")
}
```

This code reads in the value for projectname from an excel sheet and checks if each projectname that was read in exist in checkProjects.

Suppose there's a name called `FileRemoval` in checkProjects.  If the user had `fileremoval` or `Fileremoval` or any variation of the name in lower or capitalcase in their excel sheet, the above code wont catch it.  It will only catch "FileRemoval".

So my question is, how do i check for projectname in checkProjects in a case insensitive fashion?

i looked into `grep` and `grepl` but I'm concerned that that using that (if not done correctly) would end up grabbing names that have `FileRemoval` in it...i.e. "FileRemovals".

Comment: Convert all of the strings to a know case using the `tolower()` or the `toupper()` function.

Comment: @Dave2e post as answer?